# run .net app from bash script via crontab

Tags: .net, linux, shell, cron, raspberry-pi3

Im trying to execute an .net app via bash script on crontab on raspberry pi.

when I run `/home/pi/appfolder/app` runs smoothly

when I try to run `@reboot sleep 10 && /home/pi/appname/app`
or  in a shell script with name testscript.sh
`/home/pi/appfolder/app &> /home/pi/appfolder/applog.log &`

and then add on crontab

`@reboot /home/pi/appfolder/testscript.sh`

the following error raised in log

```
A fatal error occurred. The required library libhostfxr.so could not be found. If this is a self-contained application, that library should exist in [/var/tmp/.net/appname/ykc1fzqu.app/]. If this is a framework-dependent application, install the runtime in the global location [/usr/share/dotnet] or use the DOTNET_ROOT environment variable to specify the runtime location or register the runtime location in [/etc/dotnet/install_location].

The .NET Core runtime can be found at:
  - https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?missing_runtime=true&arch=arm&rid=raspbian.10-arm
```

could you please help?

Comment: Sounds like a issue with the PATH environmental variable.

Comment: Do you mean the PATH for dotnet? echo $DOTNET_ROOT /opt/dotnet

Comment: Add an echo $PATH to the script and ensure that it displays as expected when compared to echoing $PATH in your local working shell.

Comment: echo $PATH returns /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/opt/dotnet

Comment: It is strange to me I'm noob on linux because when I executed manually works